# Data binding with errror dataBindingArtifactOutputDir

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I have a weird problem when building my app.

> Cannot write to file
>   'myapp/app/build/intermediates/data-binding/dev/debug/bundle-bin'
>   specified for property 'dataBindingArtifactOutputDir' as it is a
>   directory.

It 's weird because when I clean project, I can build app. But when building app the second time, the above error happens. If I want to build app, must clean app.

I also set

```
dataBinding {
        enabled true
}
```

Thanks for any support!

Answer (score 1):

I really found the problems. I took me 1 day. I updated the gradle plugin and Android Studio to the newest version. And this is the reason why.

The newest gradle build tool is `3.4.1`, it use the gradle version `5.1.1`. When I downgrade the gradle build tool to `3.1.4` as my old project, and clean build app again error still happens. I think this way did not work but this is problem of Android Studio, it did not change the gradle version in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. I manually update to old gradle version

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

It works now luckily. Everytime Android Studio updates, the weird problems happens again. Expect everything will work well in the future. :|